# Braided Monoidal categories for quantum gravity

Tags: quantum-gravity, category-theory

We have seen that symmetric monoidal categories capture quantum theory and quantum computing quite well.  Do braided monoidal categories capture any aspects of gravitation, or are they used in quantum gravity research at all?

Comment: This question (v2) seems like a list question.

Comment: By AdS/CFT a lot of CFT questions become quantum gravity questions. CFTs tend to be simple quantum systems and has a natural categorical interpretation due to Segal, which indeed gives you braided monoidal categories. A cute example of this type of thinking in action is [a cute paper by John Baez](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.3416)